# Starting order of Apache Tomcat server.xml components

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I have been working on creating an Apache Tomcat Lifecycle listener. This listener loads certain custom configuration data from a file which are to be used within a custom valve I have developed.

I added this listener to the server.xml but it seems that before the listener's lifecycleEvent method is executed the valve is initialized.

Hence I would be grateful if one could provide me with an idea on the startup order of Apache Tomcat components which are defined within the server.xml which I believe might be useful to my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried overriding [ValveBase.initInternal()](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/ValveBase.html#initInternal%28%29) to configure the value, avoiding the listener?

> "Sub-classes wishing to perform additional initialization should override this method, ensuring that super.initInternal() is the first call in the overriding method."

Comment: I haven't, I will give it a shot and see.